# Python json memory bloat

Tags: python, json, garbage-collection

```
import json
import time
from itertools import count

def keygen(size):
    for i in count(1):
        s = str(i)
        yield '0' * (size - len(s)) + str(s)

def jsontest(num):
    keys = keygen(20)
    kvjson = json.dumps(dict((keys.next(), '0' * 200) for i in range(num)))
    kvpairs = json.loads(kvjson)
    del kvpairs # Not required. Just to check if it makes any difference                            
    print 'load completed'

jsontest(500000)

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Linux **top** indicates that the python process holds ~450Mb of RAM after completion of 'jsontest' function. If the call to '**json.loads**' is omitted then this issue is not observed. A **gc.collect** after this function execution  **does releases the memory**.

Looks like the memory is not held in any caches or python's internal memory allocator as explicit call to gc.collect is releasing memory.

**Is this happening because the threshold for garbage collection (700, 10, 10) was never reached ?**

I did put some code after **jsontest** to simulate threshold. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the top of your program

```
import gc
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_STATS)
```

and you'll get printed output whenever there's a collection. You'll see that in your example code there is no collection after `jsontest` completes, until the program exits.

You can put

```
print gc.get_count()
```

to see the current counts. The first number is the excess of allocations over deallocations since the last collection of generation 0; the second (resp. third) is the number of times generation 0 (resp. 1) has been collected since the last collection of generation 1 (resp. 2). If you print these immediately after `jsontest` completes you'll see that the counts are `(548, 6, 0)` or something similar (no doubt this varies according to Python version). So the threshold was not reached and no collection took place.

This is typical behaviour for threshold-based garbage collection scheduling. If you need free memory to be returned to the operating system in a timely manner, then you need to combine threshold-based scheduling with time-based scheduling (that is, request another collection after a certain amount of time has passed since the last collection, even if the threshold has not been reached).

Comment: Even if we call jsontest multiple times the memory does remain at ~450MB. Is this the memory used by last jsontest call ? This code is part of a webapp which processes json messages. Even after running the webapp for one hour the memory doesn't seem to be released. Is there a workaround for this other than gc.collect ?

Comment: Try printing `gc.get_count()` after each call to `jsontest` and all should be clear. Also, what's wrong with calling `gc.collect`?