# Cleaning memory after loading data from a JSON

Tags: python, json

I am loading a JSON file to parse it and convert it (only a part of the JSON) to a CSV.
So at the end of the method I would free the space of the loaded JSON.

Here is the method:

```
def JSONtoCSV(input,output):
   outputWriter = csv.writer(open(output,'wb'), delimiter=',')
   jsonfile = open(input).read()
   data = loads(jsonfile)

   for k,v in data["specialKey"].iteritems():
      outputWriter.writerow([v[1],v[5]])
```

How do you free the space of the "data" variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
del data
```

should do it if you only have one reference. Keep in mind this will happen automatically when the current scope ends (the function returns).

Also, you don't need to keep the `jsonfile` string around, you can just

```
data = json.load(open(input))
```

to read the JSON data directly from the file.

If you want `data` to go away as soon as you're done with it, you can combine all of that:

```
for k,v in json.load(open(input))["specialKey"].iteritems():
```

since there is no reference to the data once the loop has ended, Python will free the memory immediately.

Comment: Thanks, but even If I delete the variable, it didn't free space

Comment: @Oto Did you try my final suggestion? Also, are you sure this is necessary to worry about? Don't optimize until you know there is actually a problem.

Comment: It shuld be free (as in empty). It's just still allocated to the interpreter and might get reused. IIRC

Comment: I@agf I didn't tried your suggestions because I ommit a line of code where I use the data variable just before the loop.

Comment: @rpInt so the space is allocated by python but it is free space?

Comment: @Oto The memory from the variable is definitely freed. That doesn't mean that Python gives back the memory (as rpInt said) -- Python might keep the memory to use for something else -- but it's available.

Comment: Or, more likely, the memory isn't being used by python, but because of memory fragmentation, the size of the data segment can't be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, variables are automatically freed when they go out of scope so you shouldn't have to worry about it. However if you really want to, you can use

```
del data
```

One thing to note is that the garbage collector probably won't kick in immediately, even if you do use `del`. That's the downside of garbage collection. You just don't have 100% control of memory management. That is something you will need to accept if you want to use Python. You just have to trust the garbage collector to know what it's doing.

Comment: `del` is a statement not a function -- the parenthesis are not necessary.

Comment: Also, reference counting will free memory immediately when the count reaches zero -- it's independent of the garbage collection process, which is for circular references etc.

Comment: Using `del` not only means that the GC won't kick in immediately (the timing of ready-to-collect stuff varies by Python implementation), it doesn't imply that the object the name had been bound to may be collected at all.

Answer (score 1):

The data *variable* does not take up any meaningful space—it's just a name. The data *object* takes up some space, and Python does not allow you to free objects manually. Objects will be garbage collected some time after there are no references to them.

To make sure that you don't keep things alive longer than you want, make sure you don't have a way to access them (don't have a name still bound to them, etc).

An improved implementation might be

```
def JSONtoCSV(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as f:
        special_data = json.load(f)[u'specialKey']

    with open(output_filename,'wb') as f:
        outputWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for k, v in special_data.iteritems():
            outputWriter.writerow([v[1], v[5]])
```

This doesn't ever store the string you called `jsonfile` or the dict you called `data`, so they're freed to be collected as soon as Python wants. The former improvement was made by using `json.load` instead of `json.loads`, which takes the file object itself. The latter improvement is made by looking up `'specialKey'` immediately rather than binding a name to all of `data`.

Consider that this delicate dance probably isn't necessary at all, since as soon as you return these references will cease to be around and you've at best sped things up momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a garbage-collected language, so you don't have to worry about freeing memory once you've used it; once the `jsonfile` variable goes out of scope, it will automatically be freed by the interpreter.

If you **really** want to delete the variable, you can use `del jsonfile`, which will cause an error if you try to refer to it after deleting it.  However, unless you're loading enough data to cause a significant drop in performance, I would leave this to the garbage collector.

Comment: when I call this method, It doesn't free space even after the method finish it work

Comment: Garbage collection and reference counting are actually two different mechanisms in Python -- it's reference counting that will free the memory, not garbage collection, in most cases.

Comment: @Oto - Wait, do you want to *delete the file*, then? That's very different from freeing memory.

Comment: @agf - Reference counting is technically a form of garbage collection.

Comment: In the general meaning, yes, but with CPython, garbage collection is a specific optional process, separate from reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Python json memory bloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536510/python-json-memory-bloat). Garbage collection is not kicking-in as thresholds are not met. So even a del call will not free memory. However a forced garbage collection using gc.collect() will free up the object.